# Spinner in Jasonette

Tags: spinner, jasonette

I can`t find the Spinner in the Jsonette component list. Is there any replacement to allow the user to choose an item from the list? or should I develop the component as explained in the Jaonette documentation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I could not find a spinner so have written my own (very primitive). Below is the code:

```
    public class JasonSpinnerComponent {
    public static View build(View view, final JSONObject component, final JSONObject parent, final Context context) {
        if(view == null) {
            return new Spinner(context);
        } else {
            try {
                String data = component.getString("data");
                final String[] spinnerData = data.split("\\|");
                view = JasonComponent.build(view, component, parent, context);

                JSONObject style = JasonHelper.style(component, context);
                String type = component.getString("type");
                ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>
                        (context, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,
                                spinnerData);
                spinnerArrayAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout
                        .simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                ((Spinner)view).setAdapter(spinnerArrayAdapter);

                ((Spinner)view).setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                        try {
                            ((JasonViewActivity) context).model.var.put(component.getString("name"), spinnerData[position]);
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            Log.e("Warning", e.getStackTrace()[0].getMethodName() + " : " + e.toString());
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

                    }
                });

                ((Spinner)view).requestLayout();
                return view;
            } catch (Exception e){
                Log.d("Warning", e.getStackTrace()[0].getMethodName() + " : " + e.toString());
                return new View(context);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This works for a jasonette like this:

```
{
   "type": "spinner",
   "name": "gender",
   "data": "Male|Female"
}
```

Let me repeat, this is `very` primitive and will undergo a lot of changes in future. But this can be a good starting point for someone looking for a spinner. I will be glad if it helped you.